# Serialise\Deserialize between .net web service and Android client

Tags: c#, android, .net

I have an android client that communicates with .net web service.

objToFormat is a List of my custom type.

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(object objToFormat)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (objToFormat == null) return null;
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        GZipStream zipped = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
                        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        formatter.Serialize(zipped, objToFormat);
                        zipped.Close();
                        zipped.Dispose();
                        return (stream.GetBuffer());
                    }
    }
```

In my Android client i use the ksoap2 library and i receive the serialized string from the web service.

this is my android code :

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(response, Base64.DEFAULT);


Object res = deserializeObject(decoded);
```

how do i deserialize the object ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `file stream` to deserialize the object. The example below uses a `Hashtable` to save the `deserialized` content:

```
// Declare the hashtable reference.
Hashtable responseFromWebService  = null;

// Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
try 
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
    // assign the reference to the local variable.
    responseFromWebService = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
catch (SerializationException e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
    throw;
}
finally 
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

You can find the MSDN documentation on `Deserialization` here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter.deserialize(v=vs.110).aspx

---

**EDIT in response to new information about it needing to be in Java**

Your class needs has to have `implements Serializable` unless you're using an ArrayList object (or similar) which already implements this.

You also need to cast it back to what the object was (for example, the above `hashtable`)

Usage:
`Hashtable deserializedData = (Hashtable) deserializeObject(someBytes)`

```
public static Hashtable deserializeObject(byte[] b) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b)); 
        Hashtable htable = in.readObject();
        in.close(); 

        return htable; 
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) 
    { 
        Log.e("deserializeObject", "class not found error", cnfe); 

        return null; 
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe) 
    { 
        Log.e("deserializeObject", "io error", ioe); 

        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I need to deserialize it in Android.

Comment: I see you are using C# for Android from the question tags, is this correct? What do you mean by _"I need to deserialize it in Android"_ The provided code is a general way of deserializing a data stream (as per your question) in the native language (C#). It just needs to be integrated into your current project.

Comment: The code i have posted is in c# (the web service) but i receive the information in android client and need to deserialize it in android .

Comment: You aren't clear about what language your android client is in. Is the android client in Java? C#?

Comment: My android client is in Java and the web service c#.

Comment: You weren't clear about that in your original question as Android can be written in both C# and Java. I've updated my answer with an example which should work with Java Android.

Comment: Thank you,but it doesn't work i think that the problem is with getting the bytes from the response .I am getting the byte array  .i've updated my question